# Différence entre « second » et « deuxième » — Difference between “second” and “deuxième”

Tags: adjectifs, nombres

Le français possède deux adjectifs ordinaux associés au nombre *deux*. Par exemple :

> une seconde vie / une deuxième vie
>   la seconde guerre mondiale / la deuxième guerre mondiale

Quelle est la différence entre *second* et *deuxième* ?

---

French provides two ordinal adjectives for the number *2*. For example:

> une seconde vie / une deuxième vie — *a second life*
>   la seconde guerre mondiale / la deuxième guerre mondiale — *WW2*

What's the difference between *second* and *deuxième*?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Though some claim that *second* is to be used only when there is no third, fact is they are exact synonyms, though *second* is supposedly more formal.

> **Rem.** Second et deuxième peuvent être empl. l'un à la place de l'autre, sauf dans les syntagmes figés, les loc. et les adj. numéraux ordinaux comp. (où second n'est jamais empl.). Second est plus utilisé dans la lang. soutenue, deuxième dans la lang. cour. ou techn. Selon certains grammairiens, second est préféré à deuxième quand il n'y a que deux pers. ou deux choses qui sont considérées (les suites du type premier, deuxième, troisième... sont plus fréq. que les suites du type premier, second, troisième...). Second est plus rare que deuxième dans les suites strictement temp. ou spatiales. <sup>[TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/second)</sup>

Comment: Le plus drôle, c'est que c'est ce que j'aurais répondu moi-même (second = pas de troisième). En tous cas, on l'a appris comme ça a l'école.

Comment: Et pourtant [tu traduis "the 2nd most practiced religion"](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1393/how-do-you-say-the-2nd-most-practiced-religion-in-france) par _La deuxième religion_.  Dire _la seconde religion_ serait presque insultant (une religion de bas étages?)

Comment: @rds Non. *la seconde religion la plus pratiquée* serait pour moi équivalent.

Answer (score 17):

[*Second*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/second) et [*deuxième*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/deuxi%C3%A8me) sont en première approximation synonymes. En deuxième approximation, il y a quelques différences.

Certaines personnes préfèrent employer « second » parmi deux et « deuxième » lorsqu'il y a aussi un troisième, mais ce n'est pas le cas de tous, et la distinction loin d'être systématique même chez ceux qui la font. *Second* est quelquefois légèrement plus soutenu. Les usages techniques ont tendance à privilégier *deuxième*. Il ne s'agit toutefois que de tendances.

Il y a un certain nombre d'expressions dans lesquelles l'usage de l'un ou l'autre mot s'est imposé.

> Soldat de *deuxième classe* (mais la *seconde classe* ou *deuxième classe* dans un train).
>   Le *Second Empire* (mais la *Deuxième République* ou *la Seconde République*).
>   Une *dérivée seconde* (en mathématiques).
>   Le *second degré*.
>   De *second ordre*.

Le mot *second* ou *seconde* a un certain nombre de sens supplémentaires :

- En tant qu'adjectif ou que nom, il peut vouloir dire « qui assiste le premier ». *Deuxième* est plus rare dans ce sens (et inutilisé en tant que nom). *Un second couteau* (une personne peu importante dans une organisation). Un *second* dans un duel. Le *second* sur un navire (officier juste en-dessous du capitaine).
- En tant qu'adjectif, *second* peut aussi vouloir dire « qui est une conséquence du premier » ; *secondaire* conviendrait souvent à la place. On ne peut pas employer *deuxième* dans ce sens. L'adjectif *second* n'est alors pas un adjectif numéral, et il se place après le nom. *Une cause seconde*. Un *sens second* d'un mot.
- Le nom *seconde* a quelques sens dérivés directement de l'adjectif numéral, notamment la [classe de *seconde*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seconde_%28lyc%C3%A9e%29) et la deuxième vitesse d'une voiture.
- Le nom *seconde* a aussi d'[autres sens](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seconde), en particulier une [unité de temps](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seconde_%28temps%29) et une [unité d'angle (la seconde d'arc)](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seconde_d%27arc).

Comment: +1 pour les connotations de sens supplémentaires du terme *second*, que *deuxième*, plus neutre, n'a pas.

Answer (score 6):

Pour moi, *second* est utilisé si on parle d'un rang.

> Il est second au classement inter-régional.

Et *deuxième* dans une énumération.

> La deuxième voiture à gauche.

Mais souvent on peut utiliser les deux.

Comment: Pas d'accent sur ton clavier? :)

Comment: Clavier americain. Je suis desole pour les accents...

Comment: You may want to chime in on http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/51/facitility-to-type-accented-characters

Comment: Et comment [traduis-tu "the 2nd most practiced religion"](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1393/how-do-you-say-the-2nd-most-practiced-religion-in-francehttp://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1393/how-do-you-say-the-2nd-most-practiced-religion-in-france)? Si c'est un classement, ceal devrait être _la seconde religion_, mais je trouve que cela ne va pas du tout (insiste sur un caractère temporel, ou dénigre une religion de bas étages?)

Comment: La religion est un bon test des valeurs de second et deuxième, en ce qu'elle est a priori exclusive. La langue serait un bon candidat aussi : langue maternelle exclusive (quoique : la langue paternelle peut en être différente), langues apprises successivement.

Comment: @rds On dirait « *la deuxième religion la plus pratiquée* » ou « *la deuxième religion en nombre de pratiquants* ». Je suis d'accord que je trouve *seconde* dans ce contexte pas du tout idiomatique.

Comment: « Il est deuxième au classement inter-régional » et « la seconde voiture à gauche » me paraissent tout à fait idiomatiques.

Answer (score 3):

La [réponse de Portal Brony2040](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/215/79) ouvre la réflexion dans le bon sens.
Pour mémoire :

> Second est utilisé si on parle d'un rang. […] Et deuxième dans une énumération.

La religion est un bon test des valeurs de *second* et *deuxième*, car elle est *a priori* exclusive.

La langue serait un bon discriminant aussi :

- langue **maternelle** : exclusive, sauf dans un cas intéressant : une langue paternelle différente. Donc en fonction de la maîtrise, soit une énumération (maîtrise identique), soit un classement.
- langues **apprises** : successivement (quoique les années passant, la maîtrise l'emporte sur la chronologie pour le classement… sauf égale maîtrise)

Dit-on « ma *seconde* langue maternelle » ? À mon sens :

- **oui**,

  - si elle a été apprise…  **en second** (après la première).
  - ou de façon **secondaire**, c'est-à-dire avec moins d'enjeu, d'effort ou de résultat
  - on est bien sur de l'**ordinal**, soit temporel, soit qualitatif
- **mais sinon**, on dit : « ma *deuxième* langue maternelle », ce qui insiste à mon sens sur l'égalité des deux. Donc : **énumération**.

Dit-on « ma *seconde* langue étrangère est l'allemand » ? À mon sens encore :

- **oui** :

  - si je l'ai apprise **après** l'anglais (par exemple),
  - ou si je veux signifier que je la maîtrise **moins bien**
- mais **non**, si on en a une troisième, quatrième,… (l'énumération l'emporte sur la cardinalité, faute de qualificatifs (*terne* ? *quaterne* ?) qui permettraient d'indiquer la cardinalité sur plus de deux éléments).

En conclusion, j'inverserais donc l'[énoncé de Portal Brony2040](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/215/79) :

⇒ ***Deuxième* est toujours utilisé dans une énumération (c'est-à-dire en l'absence d'ordre),**

⇒ ***Second* est utilisé pour le rang dans un ensemble de 2 éléments, et *Deuxième* pour le rang dans un ensemble plus grand**

Comment: Je ne comprends pas ce que tu veux dire sur la religion. Ni d'ailleurs ce que tu conclus sur la langue. Je ne vois pas de différence sémantique entre « ma seconde langue maternelle » et « ma deuxième langue maternelle », mais les deux me semblent étranges : si c'est une langue maternelle, il n'y a pas de langue privilégiée, ce serait donc « mon autre langue maternelle » (ou alors « ma deuxième/seconde langue maternelle en ordre alphabétique », mais c'est autre chose). Je ne vois pas d'où sort ta conclusion et je n'ai pas l'impression qu'elle soit vraie.

Comment: J'ignore si la réponse d'Alain est "fondée", mais c'est bien ainsi que j'ai toujours entendu la subtile distinction de sens entre les deux termes. A tort ou à raison ? la question est intéressante, et je trouve que cette réponse apporte des éléments.

Comment: *Prime*, *second*, *tiers*, *quart*, *quint*,… sont les vieux ordinaux qui font défaut.