# How do you say “the 2nd most practiced religion in France”?

Tags: nombres, superlatifs

The “2nd most practiced religion” part is complex for me — what would this look like in French?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'd say

> *La deuxième religion de France*

Skipping *practiced*: it should be self-evident.

If you think it mandatory, though

> *La deuxième religion la plus pratiquée en France*

Would not be incorrect.

Comment: I like this answer and agree that just skipping "practiced" is the easiest way to go. Yet in the unlikely event that someone wants to make a difference between people claiming to be of a particular religion, and people actually practicing it, you'll need to specify it.