# Précisions sur le « Second Gentleman of the United States » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, anglais, choix-de-mot, genre-biologique, politique

L'article Wikipédia [*Second Lady of the United States*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Lady_of_the_United_States) indique :

> **Second Spouse of the United States** (SSOTUS), also known as **Second Lady of the United States** (SLOTUS), or **Second Gentleman of the United States** (SGOTUS), is the informal title held by the
> spouse of the vice president of the United States, concurrent with the
> vice president's term of office.

C'est construit sur le modèle de la [*First Lady of the United States*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Lady_of_the_United_States), et on a en français la [*Première dame des États-Unis*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premi%C3%A8re_dame_des_%C3%89tats-Unis) ; on évoque la question de l'[équivalent masculin](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premi%C3%A8re_dame_des_%C3%89tats-Unis#La_question_de_l%27%C3%A9quivalent_masculin) et on parle du *Premier gentilhomme*... Mais dans le *Dictionnaire de l'Académie* on a le « Premier [gentilhomme](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9G0540) de la chambre » comme titre de charge et ce n'est évidemment pas relié...

Dans le cas d'un *époux* d'une vice-présidente des États-Unis, emploierait-on le même terme (*gentilhomme*) et s'agirait-t-il du *second* ou plutôt du *deuxième* et peut-on préciser s'il y a majuscule initiale et peut-on enfin présenter quelques exemples d'emploi si possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Sûrement pas « deuxième/second gentilhomme » car [gentilhomme](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gentilhomme) fait trop référence à l'ancien régime.

L'appellation « **second [gentleman](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gentleman)** » me semble tout à fait réutilisable telle quelle en français, sans poser de problème.

La raison principale est que *second* est l'adjectif numéral déjà utilisé en anglais et qu'il existe depuis toujours en français.

Une théorie considère que second et deuxième ne sont pas exactement synonymes avec différentes justifications, par exemple que second exclut tout troisième et il existe effectivement des cas où l'un est utilisé plutôt que l'autre mais elle ne concerne pas pour moi l'alternative « deuxième gentleman » / « second gentleman ».

Voir à ce sujet: [Différence entre « second » et « deuxième » — Difference between “second” and “deuxième”](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/211)

Comment: La raison principale est que c'est l'adjectif numéral déjà utilisé en anglais et qu'il existe depuis toujours en français. Il existe aussi une théorie qui considère que *second* et *deuxième* ne sont pas exactement synonymes avec différentes justifications, par exemple que second exclut tout troisième. Il existe effectivement des cas où l'un est utilisé plutôt que l'autre mais ce n'est pas le cas avec "deuxième gentleman / second gentleman". Voir aussi https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/211/diff%c3%a9rence-entre-second-et-deuxi%c3%a8me-difference-between-second-and-d

Comment: On dit aussi assez indifféremment *deuxième dame* ou *seconde dame*.

Comment: *No worries* à propos des votes, ce n'est pas comme si on était en Pennsylvanie ;-)

Comment: Merci ! On salue l'effort c'est pour ça mais en effet :)